# Python regex for numbers between 0-63

Tags: python, regex

I have written this regex to match the numbers in the aforementioned range but it's not working properly, for instance it matches "00" and "64", and I don't get why. My logic is "numbers between 0 or 9" or "numbers between 10-59" or numbers between "60-63".

```
import re


def six_bit_number(n):
    if re.match("([0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-3])", str(n)):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Is this just a learning exercise, or…?

Comment: It's a problem on codewars.

Comment: The _best_ way to handle this, if possible, is to just use a range check on an integer variable from your Python code.

Comment: the point is to practice regular expressions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.match` looks for a match at the start of the input, but it doesn’t mind if there’s also text *after* the match. You can add [an anchor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-34) to make sure it also checks for the end of the string:

```
r"([0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-3])\Z"
```

Comment: You also need an anchor at the beginning: `r"\A([0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-3])\Z"` (or, more idiomatically, `r"^([0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-3])$"`)

Comment: That's correct otherwise it doesnt work. I had the same mistake in my regex

Comment: @sabik not for `re.match`, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) "re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of the string"

Comment: @sabik: In addition to what ATOMP said: `$` and `\Z` aren’t equivalent in Python regex.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ry's answer, simply changing to

```
re.fullmatch
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex:

```
^([0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|(6[0123]))$ [Include Global and Multiline flag]
```

Understanding of the regex:

<kbd>[0-9]</kbd> --> Matches single-digit numbers from 0 to 9

<kbd>[1-5][0-9]</kbd> --> Matches double digit numbers from 10 to 59

<kbd>(6[0123])</kbd> --> Matches 60,61,62 and 63

Comment: Why not `^([0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-3])$`?